# Por que a função me retorna um valor inesperado?

Tags: php, funções

Por que esta função está me retornando "reprovado"?

```
$nFis = 90

function resFis(){              
    if($nFis >= 60){       
        return "aprovado";
    }
    else{
        return "reprovado";
    }
}
```

Comment: você nao está passando para a função resFis() o parametro que é $nFis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque `$nFis` não está definida na função `resFis`.

Ela provavelmente é uma variável global, então você deve alterar seu método para:

```
function resFis(){              
    global $nFis;
    if($nFis >= 60){       
        return "aprovado";
    }
    else{
        return "reprovado";
    }
}
```

Ou passa-la por parâmetro:

```
function resFis($nFis){              
    if($nFis >= 60){       
        return "aprovado";
    }
    else{
        return "reprovado";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece pois a função está testando uma variável vazia. Para solucionar faça o seguinte.

No local onde fez a chamada da função resFis(), faça:

```
resFiz($nFis);
```

E na sua função faça

```
function resFis($nFis){              
if($nFis >= 60){       
    return "aprovado";
}
else{
    return "reprovado";
}
}
```